# Laravel 4 project TokenMismatchException error when login or signup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, csrf, laravel-routing

I have a problem with login and signup in L4 page, the project works fine in my local machine. but in the production server when i try to login i get the following error

```
Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException
open: /home/artncom/app/filters.php
|
*/

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

    }
```

the login and signup works fine before one day but now i get this error. i do not now why, i try many solutions without any success.

Thanks

Comment: Probably a problem with your sessions/cookies. What session driver are you using?

Comment: I used the default dession driver  which is a file driver

Comment: So do you have write permission for the sessions? They are probably not being created...

Comment: I have come across this with some browsers, it tries to keep the old session active i.e. not regenerating the token. Instead of throwing the error, redirect to the login page, and that will make Laravel regenerate the token. Like so; `Redirect::to('/login')->with('warning', 'Your session has expired. Please try logging in again.');`

Comment: i try this solution also but fail @MattBurrow

Comment: the file permission i have on the folder is 755 @TheShiftExchange